# Subspace topology on direct limit topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X_1,\mathcal{T}_1)\subset (X_2,\mathcal{T}_2)\subset\cdots\subset (X_n, \mathcal{T}_n)$ be a sequence of topological spaces, where each $X_i$ is a closed subspace of $X_{i+1}$. Let $X_{\infty}:=\cup_i X_i$ endowed with the topology $\mathcal{T}_{\infty}$ defined as follows:

$\mathcal{T}_{\infty}=\{U\subset X_{\infty}:U\cap X_i\in \mathcal{T}_i \quad\forall i\ge 1 \}.$

Of course we assume that $\mathcal{T_n}$ is the subspace topology on $X_n$ by $\mathcal{T_{n+1}}$

*EDIT: Allow me to better write the question*

I proved that is a topology.

> Let $Y_{\infty}\subset X_{\infty}$ endowed with the subspace topology by $\mathcal{T}_{\infty}$ denoted $\mathcal{T}$and let $Y_n:=X_n\cap Y_{\infty}$ endowed with the subspace topology by $\mathcal{T}_n$ denoted $\mathcal{T'}_n.$
>   We construct as for $X_n$ the coherent topology $\mathcal{T'}_{\infty}$ on $Y_{\infty}$
>
> *Claim. If $Y_{\infty}$ is closed or open in $X_{\infty}$ then $\mathcal{T'}_{\infty}=\mathcal{T}.$*

1. $\mathcal{T'}_{\infty}\subset \mathcal{T'}$

Indeed let $U\in \mathcal{T'}_{\infty}$ which means that for all $n,\quad U\cap Y_n\in \mathcal{T'}_n$. By definition of subspace topology I can write for all $n$,  $U\cap Y_n=\omega\cap Y_n$ for $\omega\in \mathcal{T_n}.$

By induction on $n$ and using the fact that $X_n\subset X_{n+1}$ I have  $U\cap Y_n=Y_{\infty}\cap (\omega'\cap X_n)$ with $\omega'\in \mathcal{T}_{\infty}.$

2. $\mathcal{T'}\subset\mathcal{T'}_{\infty}$

First, $Y_{\infty}$ is closed if and only if for all $n,$ $Y_{\infty}\cap X_n$ is closed.

Let $U\in \mathcal{T}$ so that $U=Y_{\infty}\cap \omega,\quad \omega\in \mathcal{T}_{\infty}.$

I have to prove that $U\in \mathcal{T'}_{\infty}$ which is equivalent to prove that for all $n, U\cap (X_n\cap Y_{\infty})\in\mathcal{T'}_n$ which is equivalent to $$\forall n\in \Bbb{N},\quad U\cap(X_n\cap Y_{\infty})=O\cap Y_n\quad,O\in\mathcal{T_n}.$$

Not sure how can I continue

Comment: For your first Q, using only $X_{\infty}=\cup_iX_i$ it is easily shown that $T_{\infty}$ is closed under arbitrary unions and finite intersections   and that $\cup T_{\infty}=X_{\infty}$ and $\phi \in T_{\infty},$  so $T_{\infty}$ is a topology on $X_{\infty}.$

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to show that the coherent topology (a.k.a .the direct limit topology) commutes with taking (closed) subspaces? At least in the case of a tower of closed subspaces? Why do you think this holds? From some textbook?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I edited the question. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Do you think the result if false?

Comment: @JeSuis I'm not sure yet. A coherent topology is a final topology construction, while subspaces are an initial one (in topological category terms). Such usually do not mix very well (think of products of quotient maps, which need not be quotient, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the coherent topology can be defined for any
collection of spaces without any requirements such that one 
be a closed subspace of another.

The proof that a the topology of a subspace of the coherent topology 
is the coherent topology of the subspaces, requires, as you noticed, 
that the subspace is open for just one direction of the inclusions.

When the subspace is closed, for those two topologies to be the same 
could be why the other requirements, that the spaces be a nest of 
closed spaces.  I've yet to find out.

A discussion about the coherent topology has been started in the 
ASCII only web site.
http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist&task=list
Post there for details of my proofs or write marsh@panix.com.